# Binding ObservableCollection to ListView in MVVM - show specific property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I got a model:

```
public class MyModel{
     public ObservableCollection<MyObject> myObject {get; set;}
}
```

And inside of it a "MyObject" object

```
public class MyObject{
     public int number {get; set;}
     public string name {get; set;}
}
```

This is the relevant part of my ViewModel:

```
private MyModel theModel = new MyModel();
public MyModel TheModel {get; set;}
```

This is the View

```
<ListView.BindingContext>
   <viewmodel:MyViewVM/>
</ListView.BindingContext>
<Label Text="{Binding myModel.myObject.number"} .... />
```

- Why does it only show the last number?
- How can I say the following: ItemsSource should be the Model; But in the list, there should be only shown the "number" or "name" property of the object inside the model?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using this [ListView from System.Windows.Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should be using [the one in System.Windows.Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview(v=vs.110).aspx), that's the WPF one.

Once you're using the correct one, you change your XAML to this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myObject}" DisplayMemberPath="number">
    <ListView.DataContext>
        <local:MyModel />
    </ListView.DataContext>
</ListView>
```

The other classes are mostly unchanged, I just added some sample data:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
        myObject = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>
        {
            new MyObject { name = "John", number = 5 },
            new MyObject { name = "Jane", number = 6 },
            new MyObject { name = "Sam", number = 9 },
            new MyObject { name = "Lara", number = 16 }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> myObject { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

If you add a new element to the `myObject` collection (BTW I recommend using PascalCase for public property names) the UI will be updated.
Note, if you change one of the `MyObject` element properties (`name` for example) you won't see that on the UI.

For proper change notification, implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.